# Facebook Auth and own secure token from my server

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm working on a js application, to log in I have created my authentication method that returns a token that the application uses. Now, I want to add facebook authentication by JS. It's working fine but I don't once I authenticate to facebook generate a token.

How this is typically handle?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit:

To clarify more the question this is what I'm doing in the authentication process before facebook:

```
$.post(serverURL+/authenticate, {
  username: ...
  password: ...
},function() {
  document.location = serverURL + /home?token=[hashcode] 
}
```

So to enter the system I'm using this short life token that I use for each request to the services.

So now that I have facebook, I don't know once that I have authenticate to it get a token, obviously I could implement a service to get one but I'm not sure if this is save since you can access the service directly and generate a token.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand the problem from the description that you've posted here. Try to edit the question and elaborate what exactly the problem is (provide some code, if possible).

Comment: Hi, Rahil. I have updated the question. My problems is that I need to generate a token to access to my system, so I don't know how to generate one based on the information that I get from the response from facebook.

Comment: _“but I'm not sure if this is save since you can access the service directly and generate a token.”_ – well then check the Facebook login token first for whether it’s genuine or not – either by making an API request with it to get the user’s details, or by [debugging it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug).